# CheckAccessCore return False Raises 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, api, wcf, httprequest

I am trying to implement the Basic Authorization for my WCF Rest API Calls.
All seems good and if the user is valid user, he is authenticated and the call is sent over for processing to the respective APIs.

Also, if the Auth header is not present, it throws an exception and raises 401 - Not Authorized, which seems legit.

However, when the Auth Header is provided and its not correct, it returns "FALSE" which I believe is by design for the "`CheckAccessCore`" method.

Whenever False is retuned, it raises a 400 Bad Request to my call which seems to be not right as Bad Request could be for legitimate reasons like passing different parameters to API then expected etc.

Below is my `CheckAccessCore` method

```
protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:
            var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
            if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
            {
                var svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                        .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                        .Split(':');
                var user = new { Name = svcCredentials[0], Password = svcCredentials[1] };
                if ((user.Name == "user1" && user.Password == "test"))
                {
                    //User is authrized and originating call will proceed
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //not authorized
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MyWCFService\"");
                //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401
                throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
```

And the API Call is through C# code as below:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);

            //Add a header to the request that contains our credentials
            //DO NOT HARDCODE IN PRODUCTION!! Pull credentials real-time from database or other store.
            string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user1" + ":" + "test"));
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);

            //Just some example code to parse the JSON response using the JavaScriptSerializer
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse svcResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    return svcResponse.GetResponseStream();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The question here is that

1. Is it correct for the `CheckAccessCore` method to raise a 400-Bad Request when authentication fails ?
2. If not, whats wrong with the code and how can it be corrected.

Thanks
Ashutosh

Answer (score 4):

You need to set StatusCode and then return false, try this:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
return false;
```